# Combining multiline variables as columns in bash

Tags: bash

I have to multi-line string variables each with an equal number of lines. I'm trying to make each a column of a new variable called seqinfo, but I am getting a syntax error. Any idea what the problem is?

Code:

```
seqinfo=$(paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2"))
```

Error message:

```
command substitution: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution: line 13: `paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2"))'
```

Comment: The error message looks vaguely like you are in `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Are you sure the script is being run by `bash`? Does it begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: The file name is test4.sh. Inside the file, it begins with #!/bin/bash

Comment: What does /bin/bash point too?

Comment: When I run this command: ```readlink -f bin/bash```
This is my output:
```/usr/bin/bash```
I'm not sure if this answers your question...

Comment: Judging from the line number shown in the error message, I suppose the
mentioned statement is a part of longer codes. Would you provide longer
but minimum set of lines to reproduce the error, or make sure the posted
single line alone (removing other lines) still causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this :

```
var1='
some
fruits
now'

var2='
even
more
lines'

echo "${var1}${var2}"
```

Output

```
some
fruits
now
even
more
lines
```

Regards!